# Show that a linear functional T is bounded if and only if it is Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

A functional $T$ on a normed linear space $X$ is said to be Lipschitz provided there is a $c \geq 0$ such that $|T(g) - T(h)| \leq c \|g -h\|$ for all $g, h \in X$ The infimum of such c's is called the Lipschitz constant for $T$. Show that a linear functional is bounded if and only if it is Lipschitz, in which case its Lipschitz constant is $\|T\|_*$

My Try:

$“\Rightarrow"$

Consider $T: X \to \mathbb{R}$ bounded on $X$ $\Leftrightarrow \exists M \geq 0$ such that $|T(f)| \leq M \|f\| $ for all $f \in X$  and the norm $\|T\|_* = M$

Let $f, g \in X$ , by linearity of $T$
$$|T(f) - T(g)| \leq \|T\|_* \|f - g\|$$ Consider $c = \|T\|_*$ $\Rightarrow T$ is Lipschitz

$“\Leftarrow"$

Assume $T$ is not bounded, then there is a $M$ such that $|T(f)| \geq M\|f\|$ and i am stuck

Comment: For the converse, try using the Lipschitz condition with one of the elements being 0.

Comment: You mean $|T(f) - T(0)| \geq M||f-0||$, which is a contradiction with the assumption that T is Lipshitz

Comment: That works, but there's no need to aim for a contradiction. You can just get it directly by noting $|T(f)| = |T(f) - T(0)| \leq c \|f - 0\| = c\|f\|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the second part your assumption that $T$ is not bounded implies that:
$$
\forall M \gt 0 \exists f \cdot |Tf| \gt M
$$
then you can use Lucas' argument for your contradiction